# No such file or directory but all files in the same folder

Tags: python, selenium, directory, path

I'm getting a
`No such file or directory: 'SnP1000_TICKR.csv'` error but all my files are in the following folder:

[image]

and I'm calling the file here

[image]

which is running on this piece of code:

```
def finVizEngine(input,output):
    import chromedriver_autoinstaller
    chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    ipo_df = pd.DataFrame({})
    openFinViz()
    with open(input, 'r') as IPO_List:
        csv_reader = reader(IPO_List)
```

This was running before, but then I uploaded files to `Github` and started running the files from `vscode` instead of `pycharm` and started to get a load of errors, but honestly don't understand what is wrong. Any help would be amazing,

Best Joao

Comment: Python doesn't care what directory the script it is. All Python cares about is your [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory), which is probably the root of your project.

Comment: How do you run your script exactly? E.g. VS Code debugger, VS Code integral terminal?

Comment: It's likely you need to do `finVizEngine('Scripts/SnP1000_TICKR.csv, SnP1000_DATA.csv)` since `SNP1000` is your base project folder

Comment: Also naming a variable `input` is a bad practice as it's the name of an in-built function.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).

Answer (score 0):

First check in which folder it runs code

```
import os

print( os.getcwd() )
```

`cwd` means `Current Working Directory`.

If it runs in different folder then you have script then it also search csv in different folder.

The simplest method is to use `"/full/path/to/SnP1000_TICKR.csv"`.

But more useful method is to get path to folder with `script` - like this

```
BASE = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

and use it to create full path to file `csv`

```
input_full_path  = os.path.join(BASE, "SnP1000_TICKR.csv") 
output_full_path = os.path.join(BASE, "SnP1000_DATA.csv")

finVizEngine(input_full_path, output_full_path)
```

---

**BTW:**

If you will keep `csv` in subfolder `data` then you will need

```
input_full_path = os.path.join(BASE, "data", SnP1000_TICKR.csv")
```